# Why is my JavaScript DOM traversal not working?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two checkboxes on a form. When somebody checks the second box, my JavaScript checks to make sure the first box is checked. If the first box is not checked, then my JavaScript checks it. For some reason, however, my DOM traversal is not working like it should, and the first box is not getting checked; instead, I am getting an "TypeError: firstCheckbox is null" on line 10 (the "if" statement). Why is this not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setMe(secondCheckbox){
                // alert(secondCheckbox.parentNode.previousSibling.nodeName);
                var firstCheckbox = secondCheckbox.parentNode.previousSibling.lastChild;
                if(secondCheckbox.checked && !firstCheckbox.checked){
                    firstCheckbox.checked = true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <table border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="input01">input01</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="input01" name="input01">
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <label for="input02">input02</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="input02" name="input02">
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <label for="input03">input03</label><br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="input03" name="input04">
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <label for="input04">input04</label><br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="input04" name="input04" onChange="setMe(this);">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <button type="submit">submit</button>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <button type="reset">reset</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be selecting "whitespace" in the document instead of the element.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling

Comment: All your labels point on the same input.

Comment: Why dont you just select the correct element by its id? ie `document.getElementById("input03")`, as a side note your last two checkboxes have the same name

Comment: @PatrickEvans I can't. What I didn't show is multiple rows of the same type of inputs being generated by JavaScript via AJAX. The weird thing is that my function works on those rows, just not the "static" row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `previousSibling` doesn't mean `previousSiblingElement` but instead means `previousSiblingNode` and similarly so for `lastChild`.

You need to change your code to avoid text nodes which are added automatically based on your html file's formatting.

A sample traversal for you would be (I haven't tested/debugged this, just typing in the editor here):

```
var prev = secondCheckbox.parentNode.previousSibling;
while (prev.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  prev = prev.previousSibling;
}
// prev now points to the previousElementSibling
var lastChild = prev.lastChild;
while (lastChild.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  lastChild = lastChild.previousSibling;
}

// lastChild should have the element you're looking for
```

Comment: Any suggestions ... that don't involve addressing it's ID directly?

Comment: You can still traverse the DOM, but keep looping on previousSibling until `previousSibling.nodeType === ELEMENT_NODE` and then select lastChild and loop again with `previousSibling.nodeType === ELEMENT_NODE`

Comment: This way, step 1 will give you the previous *element* and then step 2 will give last *element* child of that element

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "keep looping".

Comment: added some (probably buggy) code. Please test it out properly before use

Comment: :) Just because I say its probably buggy doesn't mean you should change ELEMENT_NODE to "TH". Also *`lastChild`* is the desired element, not `prev`.

Comment: Ah, well, my browser yelled at me about "ReferenceError: ELEMENT_NODE is not defined". http://jsfiddle.net/h7s2ns0u/2/

Comment: heh, I'm out of touch completely, it was `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` or 1 if you want to be less verbose (but less readable). Sorry about that

Comment: :) Glad to be of service.